# Creating a completely custom pagination component for tabulator

Tags: javascript, pagination, tabulator

Is there any way with which we can create a custom pagination component for `tabulator`?

**I don't want to :**

1. Add custom controls to the `Footer`. *(Already Checked Footer docs)*
2. Put the `pagination` element in a custom container. *(Already checked with Pagination docs)*

**Use case:**

Suppose I want to use a third party paginator for it's theming and interactivity options. Is there a way by which I can just apply the pagination classes to it and it will work as expected ?

Answer (score 0):

Tabulator is a modular system, you could easily either modify the existing pagination module, or create your own from scratch.

There is a guide to [Building Your Own Module](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.1/module-build) along with several [Example Modules](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.1/module-examples) to show how things work in practice.

If you want a good starting point for the pagination module then why not start with the source code for the existing pagination module, which you can find [Here](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/blob/master/src/js/modules/Page/Page.js)